# How to make everything in a textfield be capital letters / uppercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, capitalization

I want to make everything I write in a textfield to be capital letters. As I write, not after losing focus.

How do I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I would use CSS for this.

Just add `text-transform: uppercase` to your styling, and then on the server side you can convert it to uppercase.

```
input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: You can add a class, or this style, programatically with jQuery if you wish, but this is probably what you need.

Comment: +1, nice, i was also thinking all kinds of jquery / js solutions, but this is better

Comment: excellent, I had a background image for the input fields I wanted uppercased, and this is PERFECT! THANK YOU!

Comment: For some reason that does not work on IE6 :/  any ideas why??

Comment: @fgualda, I'm afraid I don't know, sorry. It should work. According to the CSS compatibility (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx) it should be working. I'd suggest asking on doctype.com. They're more likely to be able to help with styling issues.

Comment: My only issue with this is that it also causes the placeholder text to be uppercase.

Answer (score 16):

```
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: Valid point, should be combined with Brandon's solution to properly change it client side.  Changed the code slightly to update on keypress.

Comment: I removed my downvote because it now does what the OP asks. But if I were a user of a website that did this "keyup" change, **I'd hunt down the person responsible**. Seeing the letters change as you type is disorienting, and trying to go back to edit what you typed is frustrating because the cursor keeps moving to the end. http://jsfiddle.net/HPapz/1/

Comment: You are correct hence my comment above, I voted for the CSS solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use
`oninput='this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();`
This event is just for such cases, is fired after user input (pressing key) but before updating (displaying value), so with this typed text won't flicker while converting, and value is also correct (not like using only style to alter display without changing real data).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use combination of these.

using the text-transform style only renders the type in upper-case, although the value may well be lower case.

The javascript will only change current text to upper once the field changes or focus is lost

you can use gazler's jquery or simply inline javascript

e.g. onblur='javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();'

This means that the text value will appear uppercase and actually be uppercased when the value changes / control loses focus.

HTH
Sam

Comment: The one issue with onblur is that if the user simply hits the enter key, say to submit a form, the text will not be uppercased.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Gazler's answer, an enhanced solution that better handles modifier keys ( assuming that you have a placeholder of mixed case and cannot set `text-transform: uppercase;` ):

```
$('.search-input input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    var u = v.toUpperCase();
    if( v != u ) $(this).val( u );
})
```