# How do make the text in the TEXTBOX to Capital letter when the user starts typing text in jquery

Tags: jquery

when the user starts typing the text in to the text box we need to make those letters to capital letters

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make everything in a textfield be capital letters / uppercase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858488/how-to-make-everything-in-a-textfield-be-capital-letters-uppercase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**  See chigley's answer instead.

```
$(function() {
    $('#myTextBox').keyup(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SMrMQ/

Alternately, style with CSS and do actual conversion on your back-end.

Comment: This solution has terrible usability.  You can't press left arrow to go back and correct a mistake and the cursor jumps back to the end if you click anywhere in the string and enter another character (or press 'delete').

Comment: Yup.  As you'll note, I thought better of it almost immediately and referred users to chigley's answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of a jQuery solution, I'd be tempted to use CSS to make the text inside the input to appear to be capitals (`text-transform: uppercase`), regardless of whether or not they were inputted as lower or upper case. Then when you process your data, convert the data to upper case. For example in PHP, you'd use `strtoupper()` - there are equivalent functions in most other languages I imagine you might be processing the form with!

Comment: Agreed.  Don't use jQuery for this. It's a waste since everything should be capitalized vs just a few characters.

Comment: On second thought, I agree with this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type=text]').bind('keyup', function() {
    var val = $(this).val().toUpperCase()
    $(this).val(val);
  });
});
```

Test it here :**http://jsbin.com/opobu3**

Comment: This solution also has terrible usability.  You can't press left arrow to go back and correct a mistake and the cursor jumps back to the end if you click anywhere in the string and enter another character (or press 'delete').

Answer (score 2):

Just add text-transform: uppercase to your styling, and then on the server side you can convert it to uppercase.

```
input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```