# OnChange event not triggered

Tags: javascript

I was trying to achieve to convert to uppercase while user type by attaching the following function on key up.

```
function ChangeCharCase(evt,obj,upper)

{
    if(obj.value != obj.value.toUpperCase()) 
                obj.value = obj.value.toUpperCase();
    return true;
}
```

That seems to be working fine until I attach the on change event to the input text, and figured out , the on change event is not triggered at all on IE 11 and chrome . On Firefox, it seems to be okay.

You can check the case here.

http://jsfiddle.net/zt8oqaw5/4/

You would see , the onchange event will never be triggered on the first input text on the browsers mentioned above.

Does anybody know why?

How can I achieve the character case conversion properly ? 
I can't set the css here because I do want the value to be changed actually, not just for the display.

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340100/onchange-event-does-not-fire-when-value-is-changed-in-onkeyup-event

Comment: @Rgraham, Triggering the event manually at the key up event is NOT a solution as the onchange event will always be triggered at every single key press.

Comment: `onchange` is triggered _after_ `blur` (not after every keypress), you'd need to use `oninput` for realtime conversion. Or simply use CSS to show the input value in upper case only.

Comment: @Kai Why is that an issue? You're calling `onkeyup` on each keypress anyway?

Comment: @RGraham, in normal situation, the onchange event will be triggered while the focus is lost , not at every single key press. That is actually a major issue as I am using ASP.NET webForm. 
I don't want my text box to cause the postback at every single key press.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874885/how-do-make-the-text-in-the-textbox-to-capital-letter-when-the-user-starts-typin


check this one it may help

Comment: @Kai It won't cause a postback unless you explicitly call it as you're overriding any code set by ASP.NET by using attributes. I'm still not sure why you can't just use `blur` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use the onkeyup or onblur instead of onchange for text boxes. maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: Typo error, I was doing onkeyup. OnBlur is not an option here , as I want to make conversion while typing, NOT at the end.

Comment: @Kai I think Omer's point is that Chrome/IE only fire `onchange` after blur anyway. So a keyup/blur combo will function identically

Comment: Hey Kai, I'm using Chrome and the event triggers just fine. I'm on Chrome 36 and IE11 on windows 8.1. @RGraham you are correct, forgot to mention it.

Comment: @Omer, I am using chrome 36 and IE 11 on window 7 . I'm not sure that could make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

@Update
Here is an generall [definition](http://help.dottoro.com/ljoiurdq.php)

"Occurs when the selection, the checked state or the contents of an element have changed. In some cases, it only occurs when the element loses the focus."